# RedirectResult and RedirectToRouteResult not working inside OnActionExecuting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, redirect, actionfilterattribute, onactionexecuting

RedirectResult and RedirectToRouteResult not working inside OnActionExecuting if address specified as localhost(/Account/LogIn), if i specify url as http://google.com working properly.I wrote a BaseConfig class for administer session.That OnActionExecuting method while working redirect Login url if session is null.BaseConfig class that i used inside my project as follow;

```
public class BaseConfig : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;

        if (context.Session["loggedUser"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);

            //filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            //new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Account" }, { "action", "LogIn" } });
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}

<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogIn" defaultUrl="~/Home/Index" timeout="2880" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" path="/"/>
    </authentication>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work for you? Have you tried to redirect somewhere else than `Account/Login`, say `Home/Index`?

Comment: @Zabavsky, i tried as you say but it didn't work.

Comment: Why did not work properly when specified local url?